# Problems with addRoute on maps (iOS7) with Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: ios, crash, maps, titanium, appcelerator

I'm trying to add a route to a map, on iOS7, using the addRoute function, but the application always crashes (Invalid type passed to a function at index.js).

I'm using Titanium SDK 3.2, using the iOS 7 Simulator on OSX Mavericks (Titanium Studio 3.2).

The project uses Alloy... the view file (index.xml) is quite simple:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window id="mainWindow" />
</Alloy>
```

And the controller file is:

```
var MapModule = require('ti.map');

var testPoints = [
    {latitude:38.713794262212076, longitude:-9.13338303565979},
    {latitude:38.763495, longitude:-9.093763},
    {latitude:38.71371054721669, longitude:-9.160258769989014},
    {latitude:38.69162310730725, longitude:-9.215952157974243},
    {latitude:38.7099432709518, longitude:-9.132546186447144},
    {latitude:38.71203413379506, longitude:-9.140643775463104},
];

var mySpecialRoute = ({
    name: 'personal route',
    points: testPoints,
    color: 'red',
    width : 3
});

var mapview = MapModule.createView({
    animate:true,
    mapType: MapModule.NORMAL_TYPE,
    regionFit: true,
    userLocation: true,
});

$.mainWindow.add(mapview);
mapview.addRoute(mySpecialRoute);
$.mainWindow.open();
```

The output of the error on the console is:

```
[ERROR] :  Script Error {
[ERROR] :      backtrace = "#0 () at :0";
[ERROR] :      line = 54;
[ERROR] :      message = "Invalid type passed to function";
[ERROR] :      nativeLocation = "-[TiMapViewProxy addRoute:] (TiMapViewProxy.m:364)";
[ERROR] :      nativeReason = "expected: TiMapRouteProxy, was: Object";
[ERROR] :      sourceId = 323619520;
[ERROR] :      sourceURL = "file:///Volumes/UserData/carlosserrao/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/6B21A7E6-1636-473E-9F45-33A70158A0CE/hugacity.app/alloy/controllers/routemap.js";
[ERROR] :  }
```

I have searched over the Internet for a solution, but I have tested several solutions and no one seemed to have worked. I don't have any clues on how to solve it.

Can someone help, please?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the parenthesis so mySpecialRoute becomes an object:

```
var mySpecialRoute = {
    name: 'personal route',
    points: testPoints,
    color: 'red',
    width : 3
};
```

Comment: No... I finally managed to read better the documentation and I noticed there was a change in the way routes are added to the maps. I will post the final version of the WORKING code.

Answer (score 2):

you should use createRoute method of ti.map object to add route.